# How can I send an XMPP message using C#?

Tags: c#, xmpp, pidgin

I am building an application, using C#, to use for distributing alert information at my work place. At this time we have to manually send each alert to multiple emails, a forum, a notification website, and a XMPP chat server (We use Pidgin to connect to it currently). I have been able to successfully link my application to all but the XMPP server.

I only need the code to connect to the server using one username and send a single message to a distribution user (that broadcasts what ever it receives to all other users) and then close the connection.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I should go about doing this?

Comment: Lots of libraries for it, choose one : https://xmpp.org/software/libraries.html

Comment: I was looking at agsXMPP SDK. Im not sure if I was understanding it correctly... but will the SDK have to be installed on the device that is running the application once it has been created? I want this application to be standalone. Our system admin won't want to install additional software onto the computers at work just to run one small application.

Comment: Don't know about that. But SDK is a library and you have to put that library (DLL) inside the directory, which your exe is running.